# Getting cookies stored in inappbrowser to angular application

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, ionic-native

I'm currently using InAppBrowser plugin in an Ionic Cordova app and trying to get the request cookies from the InAppBrowser itself using below codes without success. The cookie is always empty.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
    ref.executeScript({ code: "document.cookie" }, function (cookie) {
        alert(cookie);
    });
});
```

Comment: are u sure document.cookie return something and is not empty ?

Comment: when i put alert inside executeScript it returns me the cookie but inside callback i am not getting anything back.